# Minecraft Xbox - Golems only spawning with player in certain range

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I've noticed with my iron golem farm that if I am standing near it, iron golems will spawn. But the problem is, if I go to my house and wait, I don't get any golems. [According to the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Golem#Spawning) iron golems do not rely on players to spawn. I should add that when I test this, I always have the same amount of villagers.

Comment: how far away is it? too far and the entire farm unloads

Comment: It's probably about 200-300 blocks away.

Comment: player chunkload radius for PC is 220 blocks outside that *nothing actually works*

Comment: I was never aware of this limit. That really would have been nice to know before I made anything. Thank you for that.